# When I press the save button in the .cshtml file, it throws me in the catch block and gives error? Can you help me follow a path?

Tags: c#, ajax, model, controller

**YBS.Data.Classes.Errors.AddOperationCanceledException: 'SELECT * FROM AccessControlDoorOpenPersonnel WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE Id=0YBS.Models.DelayControlDoorOpenPersonnelModel model insert operation was canceled (DataVInsertMisAuthority=false)**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOQVh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CClf6.png)> jquery.min.js:4     POST
http://localhost:4000/kapigecis/GecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonelKaydet 400 (Bad Request)

> "http://localhost:4000/kapigecis/GecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonelKaydet".

When I press the save button in the .cshtml file, it throws me in the catch block and gives this error on browser console.

```
function Kaydet() {
            $('#formu').parsley().validate();
            let valid = $('#formu').parsley().isValid();

            let login = 0;
            if ($('#login').val() === "on") {
                login = 1;
            }

            if (valid) {
                let talep = {
                    Id: parseInt($('#id').val()),
                    KapiId: parseInt($('#kapiId').val()),
                    KullaniciId: parseInt($('#kullaniciId').val()),
                    FonksiyonTusu: $('#fonksiyonTusu').val(),
                    Login: parseInt(login),
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: baseUrl + "kapigecis/GecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonelKaydet",
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    method: 'POST',
                    cache: 'false',
                    data: JSON.stringify(talep),
                    success: function (data) {
                        data = JSON.parse(data);
                        if (data.length === 0) {
                            Swal('Hata', 'Tanım organizasyon işlemi yapılamadı.', 'info');
                            return;
                        }

                        if (data) {
                            toastr.success("Tanım organizasyon işlemi yapıldı");
                        } else {
                            Swal('İşlem yapılamadı', data.message, 'error');
                        }
                        $('#form1').modal("hide");
                        window.location.reload();
                        dt.draw();`your text`
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
                        Swal('Internal Server Error', data.message, 'error');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

```
  [HttpPost("GecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonelKaydet")]
    public IActionResult GecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonelKaydet(GecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonelKaydetModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            dynamic result = new JObject();

            bool login = false;
            login = NewMethod(model, login);

            ControllerGecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonel controllerGecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonel = new ControllerGecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonel();
            controllerGecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonel.KullaniciRowGuid = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            controllerGecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonel.Model = controllerGecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonel.ModelOlustur(ModelSecenek.ModelListe.GecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonel);
            GecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonelModel gecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonelModel = (GecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonelModel)controllerGecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonel.Model;
            controllerGecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonel.Model.ModelYukle(model.Id);
            gecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonelModel.GecisKontrolKapiTanimId = model.KapiId;
            gecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonelModel.TanimKullaniciId = model.KullaniciId;
            gecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonelModel.FonksiyonTusu = model.FonksiyonTusu;
            gecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonelModel.Login = login;

            if (model.Id == 0)
            {
                controllerGecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonel.Ekle();
            }
            else
            {
                controllerGecisKontrolKapiAcmaPersonel.Guncelle();
            }

            return Ok(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            AnaModelHariciMetotlari.SistemHataKaydet(e.Message, HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString() + "->" + HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["action"].ToString(), HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, "WEB", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
            return BadRequest(new { id = 0, message = "Bir Hata Oluştu. Lütfen Tekrar Deneyiniz." });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems your server code did not like the request. You did show us the client code only, so  it's difficult to guess what's wrong

Comment: I aaded a picture -relevant part of controller. (The error I get when I debug)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as (properly formatted) text. Also, please give the english translation of the error message.

Comment: YBS.Data.Classes.Errors.AddOperationCanceledException: 'SELECT * FROM AccessControlDoorOpenPersonnel WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE Id=0YBS.Models.DelayControlDoorOpenPersonnelModel model insert operation was canceled (DataVInsertMisAuthority=false).    this is error

Comment: Added contoller codes.

Comment: Please add the error text also to your question instead of posting it as comment.